# How to detect if context provider is present in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

### Context

I'm working with a hybrid next.js and react-router app. Parts of the app are handled by react-router (hash-based), and parts of it by next.js router. There are common components which use hooks related to the current routing state (e.g. `useLocation`), which crash if the react-router provider wrapper is missing.

### Problem

I would like to write a hook that returns either `useLocation` (from react-router-dom) or `useRouter` (from next.js), depending on whether it detect the react-router provider in the current context.

Then I would use this hook in common components, so that they work regardless of which context they're used in.

There is a similar solution for detecting whether to use `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect` for SSR, called `useIsomorphicLayoutEffect`. I'm thinking that a similar approach could work in my case. However, feel free to suggest different solutions.

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined`. The react-router wrapper provides a context which is used by the `useLocation` hook. Therefore I believe a generic solution for detecting the context provider would be valid here.

### Example

```
const fooCommonComponent = () => {
  // ❌ this only works when react-router-dom provider exists in the current context
  const { pathname } = useLocation(); 
  // ❌ this only works for next.js router
  const { pathname } = useRouter(); 

  // ✅ what i want
  const { pathname } = useCustomLocation();
};

const useCustomLocation = () => {
  // how to implement this?
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very familiar with the Next.js side of things, but `react-router-dom@6` has an [`useInRouterContext`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useinroutercontext) hook to return true/false if the component is rendered within a RRD routing context.

`useInRouterContext`

> The `useInRouterContext` hooks returns `true` if the component is
> being rendered in the context of a `<Router>`, `false` otherwise. This
> can be useful for some 3rd-party extensions that need to know if they
> are being rendered in the context of a React Router app.

Here's an example implementation that works for *at least* the RRD side of things.

```
import { useInRouterContext, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const useCustomLocation = () => {
  const isInRRDContext = useInRouterContext();

  return (isInRRDContext ? useLocation : useRouter)() ?? {};
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-detect-if-context-provider-is-present-in-a-react-app]

Comment: I might be wrong but maybe this check happens on runtime? if so, not so useful.

Comment: @BrightLee Yeah, it runs in the frontend when the Javascript is executed and React renders the component using the hook. React hooks aren't a solve-every-use-case tool. I imagine this would be useful if the page component/content is rendered into an app container that may or may not have a `react-router-dom` routing context, which is something a transpiler or static code analysis tool can't likely know ahead of time. Is there a particular use-case you have in mind that this isn't useful?

Comment: I mean, in general, I wish if there was a way to detect if the context is used outside of provider, e.g) JSX tree is restructured or something, provider is moved. If it checks on runtime, it means you should go to the page where it renders, then you notice there is a problem. It's still better than nothing but just searching if there is better solution.